# How to keep the state of javascript imported object with ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'd like to initialise an object with specific values, and have another object that uses the value of the previously initialized object... Better than too many words, I have the following:

```
// file1.js
export default {
  myVar1: null,
  initialize(value) {
    this.myVar1 = value
  }
}
```

The file2 imports file1 and create a function to print `myVar1`

```
// file2.js
import { myVar1 } from 'file1'

export default {
  printVar() {
    console.log(myVar1)
  }
}
```

file3 initialize file1 and uses file2 to print the value of `myVar1`

```
// file3.js
import File1 from 'file1'
import File2 from 'file2'

File1.initialize('hello world')
File2.printVar() // logs undefined
```

I want to initialize file1 and wants file2 to access the value of file1 to print it. Although its value is undefined when it gets imported.

I would like to use a factory pattern in Javascript to do that. Is there a way to achieve the following?

Thanks

Comment: You could define `getMyVar` function and expose it instead of `myVar`. Or do not destruct in `file2`

Answer (score 0):

Change your file2 to this

```
import file1 from './file1'

export default {
  printVar() {
    console.log(file1.myVar1)
  }
}
```

Comment: You are probably just missing the '.', I've updated my answer.

Comment: No that's it not the problem I can access the file1 but the value of `myVar1` is null

Answer (score 0):

This is an anti-pattern to depend on the module caching and object references for such issues, regardless.

you need to import the whole file to get the reference instead of the actual value, so you have to do:

```
import file1 from './file1'

export default {
  printVar() {
    console.log(file1.myVar1)
  }
}
```

this way u dont just import the value of `myVar1`, you import a reference to the object, so you can modify the object content and always get it reflected everywhere.

P.S. this is NOT recommended, and NOT good composition.

Comment: I am playing with javascript right now, I'm not new with it but I'm wondering what could be the different ways to achieve this type of composition or how to achieve them in a better way. I have tried to import the entire file and unfortunately that still doesn't work in my case.

Comment: composition is "composition is the process of combining two or more functions to produce a new function. Composing functions together is like snapping together a series of pipes for our data to flow through." read this https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-function-composition-20dfb109a1a0

Comment: I am mostly looking at the Factory pattern right now: https://developers.caffeina.com/object-composition-patterns-in-javascript-4853898bb9d0

Comment: @alexmngn but the pattern uses functions, not objects, (classes are functions afterall), it mixes the object with the prototype of a function object using `Object.assign`, but this doesnt make the above statement less valid